# How can remove the gaps between bars?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

The code underneath works but my problem is that it prints spaces in between the bars in the histogram and I want zero space in between each bin. Any suggestion is appreciated - appreciation!

```
sns.histplot(stat='frequency',data=df, x="Water",color = "red", bins=10,
             alpha = 0.3, kde = True, line_kws = {'color':'red','linestyle': 'dashed'})
```

[image]

I want something like the below plot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `edgecolor`, which is passed through to [`Axes.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar). As an example:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

sns.histplot(stat='frequency', data=tips, x='total_bill', color='red', 
             kde=True, alpha=0.3, edgecolor=None, 
             line_kws = {'color':'red','linestyle': 'dashed'})
```

[image]

Or if you want an edge, then:

```
edgecolor='red'
```

[image]